# ctx.drawImage from canvas dynamically created in js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Alphabet-C-Transparent-File.png';
document.body.appendChild(image);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500);
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If I use ctx.drawImage(...) with the canvas created in js, it will not work.
If I use fillRect(...), it does draw rectangle as intended.
At least in Vscode. It doesn't draw rectangle in this code snippet thing.
I cannot figure out why this is.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: In the code, you use `letter` in `drawImage()`, but `letter` isn't declared anywhere. Have you tried it with using `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500);` instead?

Comment: Sry that's typo. Yes I did try with 'image' and it won't work.

Comment: You aren’t waiting for the img to finish loading.

Comment: how can I wait for the image to finish loading?

Comment: ..so it worked for me the second time of running the snippet I guess because the image was already in cache.

Comment: addEventListener load on the img and do the drawing then.

Comment: For me, no matter how many times I run I dont have the image inside the canvas. only outside from body.appendChild()

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the image hs loaded before drawing it on the canvas.

This snippet adds an event listener to the img element and draws it when the load event fires.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Alphabet-C-Transparent-File.png';
document.body.appendChild(image);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
image.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```